# Cakephp cookie return encrypted data

Tags: cakephp-2.7

Could anyone help me?
When i read cookie in live server, cookie return encrypted data in live server. But in local cookie return decrypted data.
Cookie config is as the following

```
$this->Cookie->name = 'rememberMe';
$this->Cookie->secure = false;
$this->Cookie->key = 'key';
$this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
$this->Cookie->type('rijndael');
```

i want cookie return decrypted data when read cookie.
anyone can help me?